# AVPlayerViewController Playback Control Rewind/Forward Not Working

Tags: ios, avplayer, mp4, avplayerviewcontroller

I'm able to get the AVPlayerViewController to display properly via presentViewController.  The Play and Pause buttons work as expected, but the Fast Forward/Backward buttons don't do anything...  I've looked over the documentation but haven't seen any mention that I need to explicitly implement a gesture function for them.

I'm not doing anything special to instantiate the AVPlayerViewContoller with a local video file in **mp4** format:

```
let videoURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
let player = AVPlayer(URL: videoURL!)
let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()

playerViewController.player = player
self.presentViewController(playerViewController, animated: true) {
  playerViewController.player!.play()
}
```

What am I missing?  I find it hard to believe no one else has come across this.

I think it could possibly be:

1. Because it's a local mp4 file.
2. I need to implement the touch callbacks for ff/fb manually.
3. ???